# Add Image to JMenu

Tags: java, jmenu

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add an icon besides the text on a JMenu. Everywhere I've looked on the internet I've only found how to add an icon on a JMenuItem but nothing on the JMenu itself.
Can someone help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JMenu` extends `JMenuItem` which in turn extends `AbstractButton`. Both `JMenu` and `JMenuItem` inherit `setIcon` from `AbstractButton`. This is the same method that gets called when you create a `JMenuItem` with an `Icon` in the constructor. For `JMenu` you'll have to call it separately.